# push not sent in push io for android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have followed https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCFA/android/step-by-step/ to integrated push notification for Android. 
After writing the code, when I try to send a test push from the console https://manage.pushio.com/ the push is not received in the mobile, no errors shown in the logcat. I'm able to get the push io device id.

Here is the logcat for your refernce:

```
 11-22 17:40:45.884 7995-7995/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-22 17:40:45.884 7995-7995/? D/dalvikvm: Try to disable coredump for pid 7995
11-22 17:40:45.884 7995-7995/? D/dalvikvm: Process 7995 nice name: com.push.io
11-22 17:40:45.884 7995-7995/? D/dalvikvm: Extra Options: not specified
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Push IO Manager - version: 6.29.1
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: LEP PushIOLocalEventProcessor loaded
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: PH registerPushMessageListener
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: EM registerPushIOEventListener
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Detecting notification service...
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 196: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-22 17:40:46.034 7995-7995/com.push.io D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00d1
11-22 17:40:46.044 7995-7995/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzm
11-22 17:40:46.044 7995-7995/com.push.io W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 433: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-22 17:40:46.044 7995-7995/com.push.io D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001b
11-22 17:40:46.054 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Google Play Services found, using GCM for notification service.
11-22 17:40:46.054 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: mRegisteringNotificationPreferences: null,mScheduledNotificationPreferences: null
11-22 17:40:46.054 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Get All PushIO Preferences
11-22 17:40:46.054 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: mPushIOPersistenceManagerMap: 0
11-22 17:40:46.054 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Registering device with 'GCM' servers...
11-22 17:40:46.064 7995-7995/com.push.io W/ContextImpl: Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:495 com.pushio.manager.PushIOManager.registerWithNotificationService:355 com.pushio.manager.PushIOManager.scheduleRegistration:294 
11-22 17:40:46.104 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Your PushIO Device ID is: b533a96c-0443-4a8f-abce-6f425b7e5182
11-22 17:40:46.134 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
11-22 17:40:46.144 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
11-22 17:40:46.144 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
11-22 17:40:46.144 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
11-22 17:40:46.144 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
11-22 17:40:46.154 7995-7995/com.push.io E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
11-22 17:40:46.184 7995-7995/com.push.io D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-22 17:40:46.834 7995-8035/com.push.io D/pushio: Push Broadcast
11-22 17:40:46.834 7995-8035/com.push.io D/pushio: Push registration received. id: APA91bGc80L4LLPybb17dN-Rl5vzcNkF6rsaQn_G3BO8uj6P2GO_VCcEQmYCnajHrXGHm7G9rJwioGv5mTty36KOnDcMhoa30VG-YYB-dmkh_Wr0jIwisZo
11-22 17:40:46.834 7995-8035/com.push.io D/pushio: Scheduling a new registration in 15 seconds
11-22 17:40:46.834 7995-8035/com.push.io D/pushio: Device Token= APA91bGc80L4LLPybb17dN-Rl5vzcNkF6rsaQn_G3BO8uj6P2GO_VCcEQmYCnajHrXGHm7G9rJwioGv5mTty36KOnDcMhoa30VG-YYB-dmkh_Wr0jIwisZo
11-22 17:41:01.854 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Starting registration...
11-22 17:41:01.854 7995-8272/com.push.io D/pushio: API URL: https://api.pushio.com/r/OlakwAFwXg_g59w
11-22 17:41:01.864 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 11
11-22 17:41:01.864 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 12
11-22 17:41:01.864 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 13
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 14
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 15
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 16
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 17
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 18
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 19
11-22 17:41:01.924 7995-8002/com.push.io I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 20
11-22 17:41:02.614 7995-8272/com.push.io D/pushio: Register - Request String: dt=APA91bGc80L4LLPybb17dN-Rl5vzcNkF6rsaQn_G3BO8uj6P2GO_VCcEQmYCnajHrXGHm7G9rJwioGv5mTty36KOnDcMhoa30VG-YYB-dmkh_Wr0jIwisZo&ins=1479816646&tz=Asia/Calcutta&utc=19800&appv=1.0&libv=6.29.1&cr=&mf=asus&mod=ASUS_T00J&osv=19&d=2.0&w=720&h=1280&l=en_SG&di=b533a96c-0443-4a8f-abce-6f425b7e5182&c=&npref=%7B%7D&tr=[]
11-22 17:41:02.974 7995-7995/com.push.io D/pushio: Registration with push.io servers successful!
```

Comment: I recommend you the google firebase tutorials

Comment: @ Jaco, My requirement is to use Oracle Push IO. I have used Firebase and able to get the push.